# Generate most liked posts from community

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

I'd like to automatically generate the posts with the most likes (preferably a top 5) in a community/Facebook group I'm managing. The posts are not from me, but from members of the community showing off work.

I'm wondering if this is possible, since it would make my work (reposting the post with the most likes in a company page) a lot easier. Users post quite a lot and I want to reward them with showing the most-liked work in a company page where they will gather a lot of views.